# JSON object not correctly sent to my ASP.NET MVC controller, missing properties

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an issue with passing a JSON objject to my ASP.NET MVC controller.

JSON is set in JS this way:

```
 jsonChildren = '{ "childImproItems" : [{ "Theme":"tralalali"  }, { "Theme":"tralalali"  }]}';
...
  $.ajax({
           url: url,  
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.parse(jsonChildren),
            success: function (result) {
              ...  
            },
            error: function (result) {
              ..
            }
        });
```

Inside my controller:

```
public int MyMethod(String typeName, SelectOptionsViewModel id) {
  return 0;
}
```

Concerned Model classes are as follows:

```
public class SelectOptionsViewModel {
        ...
  public List<ChildImproItemViewModel> childImproItems { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class ChildImproItemViewModel {
        ...
  public string Theme { get; set; }
}
```

The debugger correctly routes me to my controller and correctly interprets the JSON as a SelectOptionsViewModel  instance. 
It correctly sets its childImproItems  property with a list of 2 objects.
But the Theme property of the 2 childImproItems  objects is null although they are supposed to be set to a dummy value in my example.
The same happens with the other properties.

Do you guys see where is my mistake?

thx in advance.

EDIT:
Exactly the same happens if I create the JSON object myself as follows:

```
   JSONFormatChildren = {};
    JSONFormatChildren.childImproItems = {};
    JSONFormatChildren.childImproItems[0] = {};
    JSONFormatChildren.childImproItems[0].Theme = 'trouloulou';
    JSONFormatChildren.childImproItems[1] = {};
    JSONFormatChildren.childImproItems[1].Theme = 'trouloulou';
```

and then ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: url,  //We can't pass the selectId directly as C# does not know about JS variables
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSONFormatChildren,
....
}
```

Once again, the list is correctly created with the corract amount of elements (2) but all the elements Theme property = null instead of trouloulou...

EDIT 2:
If I use this JSON:

```
 jsonChildren = '{"Theme":"tralalali"}';
```

And this method:

```
 public int test2(String typeName, ChildImproItemViewModel id) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

it works fine

If I use this JSON:

```
 jsonChildren = '[{"Theme":"tralalali"},{"Theme":"tralalali"}]';
```

And this method:

```
   public int test2(String typeName, List<ChildImproItemViewModel> id) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

it does not work: id = null when method is invoked

Comment: Something I find useful when dealing with model binder issues with json is http://json2csharp.com. This will let you see what your json parses into in C# (obviously) so you can see if the problem is with your actual json or something else.

Comment: Nice URL thx for sharing :). Parsing my JSON string in it ends up with apparently correct model class though.

Comment: @AD edit your question to include the signature to your ActionResult that is accepting the JSON

Comment: @AD Another problem I just noticed is your `jsonChildren` is trying to construct JSON as a string. Forget that. Just create a Javascript object and pass that to jquery ajax function. I'll update my answer

Comment: @AD add contentType: 'application/json' to your ajax

Comment: @ Hithesh : did not help, see details in below answer comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly specify the content-type to json as default in jquery is form-url-encoded. Also, I think the JSON.Parse function is unnecessary, try it with/without it.

EDIT: I just noticed that you are trying to manually create a JSON string. That is a bad idea, just create a Javascript object and then use JSON.stringify(). Otherwise it is really easy to screw up the JSON string syntax. If you are supporting old browsers you may need to include the json2.js library

```
var     jsonChildren = { "childImproItems" 
: [{ "Theme":"tralalali"  }, { "Theme":"tralalali"  }]};
    ...

  $.ajax({
           url: url,  
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonChildren),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
              ...  
            },
            error: function (result) {
              ..
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does not seem to be the reason, if I add the contentType, then it invokes the error function and not the success function anymore.

Comment: @A D did you try it both with and without JSON.parse?

Comment: @AD If it is invoking the JS error function then your ActionResult returned an error code, likely indicating binding is failing, which BTW is your initial problem as model binding isn't working. It could lead you to the real problem, like mismatched types or something. What does the message in the error function say? What is the exception?

Comment: without JSON.parse, it is even worse, when (String typeName, SelectOptionsViewModel id)  gets invoked, idoes not recognize anymore childImproItems as a  List<ChildImproItemViewModel> .
So it has to be JSON.parse .

Comment: when specifying contentType: 'application/json', as mentionned it triggers the error gfunction and Chrome tools only specifies that an internal error 500 occured, I do not have more  visible details.
I don't think it s the cause f the issue cause if I don't specify it, the JSON is interpreted as a SelectOptionsViewModel  and its  List<ChildImproItemViewModel>  is correctly created with the correct amount of elements. Only the Theme property of each element does not work.

Comment: @AD You can look at the exact payload being sent to your server in the Chrome webtools Network tab, make sure it looks valid. you should also be able to see the exception that fails the request if you have `<customErrors mode="Off" />` it will be in the response body of the 500 error